# Sharing answers on social media

Tags: support

I see these social media sharing options once I submit an answer in SPSE.

[image]

But it disappears after some time and it does not appear for any other existing answer automatically. Is this done on purpose since we have this option instead for each question by default? Or am I missing something?

[image]

But I would prefer the former one, because its highly visible at the end of the page for sharing.

**UPDATE:** Just noticed that sharing is missing for questions in this meta site too.

Comment: Hm.. interesting... I also don't see the social media buttons on my old answers.